# Is there any algorithm which check right NPI (National Provider Identification) number?

Tags: asp.net, algorithm

Basically I'm developing application using asp.net and I want to write Custom validator which will check right NPI number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Provider_Identifier) says:

> A 10-digit NPI Number may be validated using the Luhn algorithm by
>   prefixing "80840" to the 10-digit number.

Obviously that just validates the check digit. To find whether a number is actually assigned, I think you need a list. There's an [online lookup](http://npidb.org/npi/), for example. Even without that, there may be additional checks you can do if you know anything about how HIPAA hands the numbers out.

Comment: I think so. There might be any webservice to verify NPI but i don't want to go that much of depth. Anyways thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has found this post but is looking for this in Java, here is a java program that does this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class NpiUtil {
    private static final String NPI_PATTERN_STRING = "[0-9]{10}";
    private String npi;

    public static boolean isValidNpi(final String npi) {
        return new NpiUtil(npi).isValid();
    }

    private static String fromCharCode(int... codePoints) {
        return new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
    }

    public static String generateRandomNpi() {
        Double randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999999 - 100000000 + 1) + 100000000);
        int tmp;
        int sum;
        int i;
        int j;
        String npi9 = String.valueOf(randomNumber.intValue());
        i = npi9.length();
        if ((i == 14) && (npi9.indexOf("80840", 5) == 0))
            sum = 0;
        else if (i == 9)
            sum = 24;
        else {
            return "!";
        }

        j = 1;
        while (i != 0) {
            tmp = npi9.charAt(i - 1) - new String("0").charAt(0);
            if ((j++ % 2) != 0) {
                if ((tmp <<= 1) > 9) {
                    tmp -= 10;
                    tmp++;
                }
            }
            sum += tmp;
            i--;
        }
        String checkDigit = fromCharCode(((10 - (sum % 10)) % 10 + 48));
        return randomNumber.longValue() + checkDigit;
    }

    private NpiUtil(final String npi) {
        this.npi = npi.trim();
    }

    private boolean isValid() {
        return this.npi.length() == 10 && this.complies();
    }

    private boolean complies() {
        if (!this.npi.matches(NPI_PATTERN_STRING)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Character lastDigit = this.npi.charAt(9);
        final List<Integer> everyOther = this.listWithEveryOtherDoubled(this.npi.substring(0, 9));
        int sum = 0;
        for (final Integer num : everyOther) {
            sum += sumOfDigits(num);
        }
        final int total = sum + 24;
        final int units = total % 10;
        final int checkDigit = (units != 0) ? (10 - units) : units;
        return Character.getNumericValue(lastDigit) == checkDigit;
    }

    private List<Integer> listWithEveryOtherDoubled(final String str) {
        final List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                nums.add(2 * Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i)));
            } else {
                nums.add(Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i)));
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }

    private static int sumOfDigits(final int number) {
        int num = number;
        int sum = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            sum += num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        System.out.println("1234567890".matches(NPI_PATTERN_STRING));
        System.out.println("123456789".matches(NPI_PATTERN_STRING));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class NpiUtilTest {
    @Test
    public void testNpiUtil() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            Assert.assertTrue(NpiUtil.isValidNpi(NpiUtil.generateRandomNpi())); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple way to validate the NPI.

1. Use API call to validate NPI. Reference link: https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/help-api  and data use [Querying JSON data from CMS NPI data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182306/querying-json-data-from-cms-npi-data/68499845#68499845)
2. Using the Luhn formula. Reference document  https://www.cms.gov/Regulations-and-Guidance/Administrative-Simplification/NationalProvIdentStand/Downloads/NPIcheckdigit.pdf:

Function to validate using Python 3.8:

```
kk= '1497842694'
def val_npi(NPI):
    if (len(NPI)==10):
        k = 0
        k1 = 0
        if (NPI[0] in (['1','2'])):
            for i in   NPI[:9][::2]:
                if(int(i)*2<10):
                    k = k + int(i)*2
                else: 
                    k = k+((int(i)*2) % 10)+ 1       
            for i in  NPI[:9][1::2]:
                k1 = k1+int(i)
        if((10-(k+k1+24)%10)==int(NPI[-1])):
             return True
        if ((k+k1+24)%10)==int(NPI[-1]):
             return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net function to validate NPI Number Checksum

```
Private Function ValidateNPI(ByVal sNPI As String) As Boolean
‘KP calculate the Checksum of an NPI using the Luhn Algorithm
‘This can easily be modified to return a checksum instead of a boolean ’1/17/2007.
Dim I As Integer
Dim iCnst80840Prefix As Integer = 24
Dim iRoutine1 As Integer ‘Add the 80840 prefix along with the literal even digits
Dim dRoutine2 As Double
Dim dRoutine3 As Double
Dim dRoutineResult As Double
Dim dRoutineCeiling As Double
Dim dFinalResult As Double

Try
‘example NPI without check sum is “123456789″, The checksum is 3
‘KJP add the even digits (From the left: 2,4,6,8) and the “80840″ Prefix value.
‘This returns the first value.
iRoutine1 = iCnst80840Prefix + CInt(Mid(sNPI, 8, 1)) + CInt(Mid(sNPI, 6, 1))
+ CInt(Mid(sNPI, 4, 1)) + CInt(Mid(sNPI, 2, 1))

‘KJP Loop through the odd digits(From the left: 1,3,5,7,9),
‘multiply by 2 and add the numbers (not the SUM) together
‘This returns the second value.
I = 1
Do Until I > 9
Dim sMidRslt As String
Dim dMidRslt As Double
Dim dMidRslt1 As Double
dMidRslt = Val(Mid(sNPI, I, 1)) * 2
sMidRslt = dMidRslt.ToString
dMidRslt1 = CDbl(Val(Mid(sMidRslt, 1, 1))) + CDbl(Val(Mid(sMidRslt, 2, 1)))
dRoutine2 = dRoutine2 + dMidRslt1
I += 2
Loop

‘KJP add up and calculate all of the individual pieces
dRoutine3 = iRoutine1 + dRoutine2
dRoutineCeiling = (Val(Mid(dRoutine3.ToString, 1, 1)) * 10) + 10
dFinalResult = dRoutineCeiling – dRoutine3

‘KJP result may be 10 so trim it down to the checksum of 0
If dFinalResult = 10 Then
dFinalResult = 0
End If
‘KJP Do the final comparison
If CStr(dFinalResult) = Mid(sNPI, 10, 1) Then
Return True
Else
Return False
End If

Catch ex As Exception
Logger.Trace(SeverityLevel.CriticalError, ex)
Return False
End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the poster was asking for a custom validator in asp.net, but this thread pops up first when searching for NPI Validation. So, I figured I'd give my two cents.

Below is a custom validation method for the NPI/Luhn validation using
jQuery Validator as the API. Feel free to modify and apply this where needed. This could also be modified to run as a standalone function.

Below is the best solution I have come up with so far.

```
/**
 * jQuery Luhn validator for NPI (USA) WITHOUT the 80840 Prefix
 * Instead, using 24 as the magic bit in replacement of 80840
 * This is a tad bit more verbose than it should be,
 * but you can see how the number is being moved around which is 
 * better for testing purposes.
 * https://www.cms.gov/Regulations-and-Guidance/HIPAA-Administrative-Simplification/NationalProvIdentStand/downloads/NPIcheckdigit.pdf
*/
jQuery.validator.addMethod("NPI",function(value, element){
  var npi = value;
  npi = npi.split('');
  var checkBit = npi.pop(), npi_double = [], npi_unaffected = [];
  npi.reverse();

  for (var i = 0; i < npi.length; i++) {
    if ((i % 2) === 0) { npi_double.push((npi[i] * 2)); }
    if ((i % 2) === 1) { npi_unaffected.push(npi[i]); }
  }

  npi_double = npi_double.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
  npi_unaffected = npi_unaffected.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
  var total = npi_unaffected + npi_double, total_sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
    total_sum += parseInt(total.charAt(i));
  }

  total_sum += 24; //Magic Bit
  var final = Math.ceil((total_sum)/10)*10;
  return ((final - total_sum) == checkBit) ? true : false; 
}, "Not a valid NPI Number");
```

Be sure to add this to the rules field of validation input, e.g.,

```
npi:{
        required:true,
        NPI:true
      }
```